# Why I obtain this "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'" into a SQL Server query that use between?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, rdbms

I am not familiar with databases.

I am working on Microsoft SQL Server and I have some problem trying to perform this query that uses between keyboard to select a Date range.

My query is:

```
select NumeroPolizza ,sum(v.Ctv) as Ctv_RI
from (
    select r.NumeroPolizza,SUM(r.ImportoPrestazioneIniziale)  as Ctv
    from Prestazione r with(nolock)
    where r.NumeroPolizza in (select ID from Polizza p with(nolock) where TipoSistemaProvenienzaID=8)
    --and r.DataInizio <= '2015-12-31'
    and between '2016-01-01' and '2016-04-01'
    group by r.NumeroPolizza

    UNION

    select NumeroPolizza,SUM(ImportoRivalutazioneDaPiano+ImportoRivalutazioneEstemporaneo)as  Ctv
    from Rivalutazione with(nolock)
    where NumeroPolizza in (select ID from Polizza p with(nolock) where TipoSistemaProvenienzaID=8)
    --and DAtaDecorrenza <= '2015-12-31'
    and between '2016-01-01' and '2016-04-01'
    group by NumeroPolizza
) v
group by NumeroPolizza
order by NumeroPolizza
```

As you can see I am using 2 **between** as filter of 2 **where conditions**, something like this:

```
and between '2016-01-01' and '2016-04-01'
```

the problem is that SQL Server give me the following error message:

```
 11:30:36  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 156, SQL State: S0001]  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'.
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
```

What am I missing? How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the column Name before between.

Syntax is `<column_name> between <value> and <other_value>`

Answer (score 2):

You have to state **what** is `BETWEEN`, so I guess:

```
and DAtaDecorrenza between '2016-01-01' and '2016-04-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write column name before between. Please check updated query

```
select NumeroPolizza ,sum(v.Ctv) as Ctv_RI
    from (
        select r.NumeroPolizza,SUM(r.ImportoPrestazioneIniziale)  as Ctv
        from Prestazione r with(nolock)
        where r.NumeroPolizza in (select ID from Polizza p with(nolock) where TipoSistemaProvenienzaID=8)
        --and r.DataInizio <= '2015-12-31'
        and r.DataInizio between '2016-01-01' and '2016-04-01'
        group by r.NumeroPolizza

        UNION

        select NumeroPolizza,SUM(ImportoRivalutazioneDaPiano+ImportoRivalutazioneEstemporaneo)as  Ctv
        from Rivalutazione with(nolock)
        where NumeroPolizza in (select ID from Polizza p with(nolock) where TipoSistemaProvenienzaID=8)
        --and DAtaDecorrenza <= '2015-12-31'
        and r.DataInizio between '2016-01-01' and '2016-04-01'
        group by NumeroPolizza
    ) v
    group by NumeroPolizza
    order by NumeroPolizza
```

Answer (score 0):

I have specified the datecolumn before the BETWEEN. Please refer this,

```
SELECT NumeroPolizza
    ,sum(v.Ctv) AS Ctv_RI
FROM (
    SELECT r.NumeroPolizza
        ,SUM(r.ImportoPrestazioneIniziale) AS Ctv
    FROM Prestazione r WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE r.NumeroPolizza IN (
            SELECT ID
            FROM Polizza p WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE TipoSistemaProvenienzaID = 8
            )
        --and r.DataInizio <= '2015-12-31'
        AND r.DataInizio BETWEEN '2016-01-01'
            AND '2016-04-01'
    GROUP BY r.NumeroPolizza

    UNION

    SELECT NumeroPolizza
        ,SUM(ImportoRivalutazioneDaPiano + ImportoRivalutazioneEstemporaneo) AS Ctv
    FROM Rivalutazione WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE NumeroPolizza IN (
            SELECT ID
            FROM Polizza p WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE TipoSistemaProvenienzaID = 8
            )
        --and DAtaDecorrenza <= '2015-12-31'
        AND DAtaDecorrenza BETWEEN '2016-01-01'
            AND '2016-04-01'
    GROUP BY NumeroPolizza
    ) v
GROUP BY NumeroPolizza
ORDER BY NumeroPolizza
```